# CSS sprite sheets and HTTP requests

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question regarding CSS. I have a sprite sheet that I'm trying to access from 2 classes. I do so with the following CSS.

```
.buttons, .expand:before { 
   background-image: url('images/spriteSheet2.png');
}
```

Than latter I set the background positions as needed. Is this causing 1 or 2 HTTP requests? I only want the sprite sheet to be loaded once but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: One. But even if it were causing two, the second one would be from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no extra HTTP request to the image.

There will be one to get your html page, another one to grab css (assuming it's included css file), then another one (from your css) to fetch the image.

You can check all your request with Chrome DevTools by going to Network Panel. It will give you in-depth insight of what's actually going on with your website and how many request are performed. It will also show you time and latency, size and method used. It's a great tool for further optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the same object many times inside the page, the browser doesn't request it again.